# angular custom directives cannot change value to ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jqlite

Im new to angular and I have created a custom directive for jquery timepicker plugin and this plugin is not binding with ng-model

My code is

### Console the output and it says undefined

please check out

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Time From</th>
      <th>Time To</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" ng-model="table.row1" size=6/ disabled>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text"   ng-model="table.dup_row1 " size=6 timepicki/>
        {{dup_row1}}
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

and my module is

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.directive('timepicki', [

  function() {
    var link;
    link = function(scope, element, attr, ngModel) {
      element.timepicki();
    };

    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: link,
      require: 'ngModel'
    };
  }
])
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.table={}
  $scope.table.row1 = "00:00"

  $scope.submit=function(){
    console.log($scope.table.dup_row1)
  }
});
```

Is this the proper way of making custom directive?

Any help is appreciated,

MY PLUNKER LINK http://plnkr.co/edit/ZHYvUABqHh1MVF9APrR7?p=preview

Thanks in advance

Comment: ALWAYS use an object in `ng-model`. 2 way bindings of primitives  break when child scopes get created

Comment: thanks i have changed the ng-model...please help he out ...still not binding values

Comment: Using jQuery plugin to update values you need to use events of that plugin to let angular know that scope is changing and use `$apply`. Suggest you avoid jQuery plugins until you understand angular. There are lots of angular date picker modules available

Answer (score 1):

Use of property on_change of Plugin Timepicki. OnSelect no exist in Plugin.

```js
app.directive('timepicki', function() {
      return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, el, attr,ngModel) {
          $(el).timepicki({
              on_change: function(dateText) {
                  dateFormat: 'hh:mm a',
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(dateText);
                  });
            }
          });
        }
      };
    })
```